# ¿Por que la función JS solo funciona sobre una fila de la tabla?

Tags: javascript, java, html-tabla

tengo la siguiente función en un JSP

```
    <script language="javascript">
    
    function alerta() {
    var cantidad = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Stock").textContent);
    var minimo = parseFloat(document.getElementById("minStock").textContent);
    
    if (cantidad <= minimo){
        document.getElementById("Stock").style.color="#FF0000";
    }
       
}  
</script>
```

se supone que cuando el if sea true debería cambiar el color de cada elemento con el identificador "Stock", pero resulta que solo cambia el primer elemento de la siguiente tabla:

```
                   <table id="datos" number-per-page="4" current-page=""  class="table table-striped table-sm ">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th >Descripción</th>
                            <th>Costo</th>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                            <th>Stock</th>
                            <th>Stock Mín.</th>
                            <th>Stock Máx.</th>
                            <th>Id Prov.</th>
                            <th>Id Ca.</th>
                            <th>Imagen</th>
                            <th>Actualizar / Eliminar</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="p" items="${lista}">
                        <tr id="resConsulta">
                            
                            <td>${p.getId()}</td>
                            <td class="text-break" style="max-width: 150px;">${p.getNombre()}</td>
                            <td class="text-break" style="max-width: 150px;">${p.getDescripcion()}</td>
                            <td>${p.getPrecio_compra()}</td>
                            <td>${p.getPrecio_venta()}</td>
                            <td id="Stock">${p.getStock()}</td>
                            <td id="minStock">${p.getMin_stock()}</td>
                            <td>${p.getMax_stock()}</td>
                            <td>${p.getProveedor_idProveedor()}</td>
                            <td>${p.getCategoria()}</td>
                            <td><img src="${p.getFoto()}"width="40" height="40"></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="btn-group " role="group " aria-label="Basic example ">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" onclick="location.href='./Controlador?accion=EditarProducto&id=${p.getId()}'">
                                        <img src="img/icons/actualizar.png"> Actualizar
                                    </button>
                                         
                                        <button  id="deleteItem" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="location.href='./Controlador?accion=EliminarProducto&id=${p.getId()}'">
                                        <img src="img/icons/eliminar.png">Eliminar
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        </c:forEach>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

en el body ejecuto la función así: `<body onload="alerta()">` .Alguien con mas experiencia que me pueda explicar por que sucede esto? yo apenas soy estudiante y no entiendo muchas cosas, les agradezco mucho sus respuestas

Comment: Saludos. En las páginas HTML los `id` deben ser únicos así sea tengas distintos o mismos tag; no te sugiero un valor que vayas incrementando y lo agregues a valor del `id`.

Comment: entiendo que el id debería ir cambiando y accedo a el a través de un for, si no estoy mal?

Answer (score 2):

he modificado tu alerta, primero busque todos los elementos con id Stock que puedan estar en tu tabla, luego recorro estos mismos mediante un for e inserto color a cada elemento stock de la tabla. Lo pruebas y me avisas

```
function alerta() {
    
    let element = document.querySelectorAll('#Stock');

    for(i=0; i<element.length ; i++)
    {
        element[i].style.color="#FF0000";
    }


}
```

Comment: gracias, lo estaré probando

Comment: efectivamente funciono, si accede a cada elemento con el Id Stock, muchas gracias. veré como lo modifico para que funcione la comparación que necesito